# How to display Webform label Above the field instead of Inline in Drupal 8?

Tags: webforms

In Drupal 7 it was easy to select whether I wanted the label of a field to display Above or Inline with the field.  In Drupal 8 I can't seem to find this feature. I realize this can be done in CSS, but that seems like a kludgy way to do it if there is just a tickbox somewhere that I am missing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Ben, Let me know you webform version I can guide where you can get that option.

As of now I am using webform version 8.x-5.0-beta15 & it seems your requirement is available in this module. Below are steps for same

1. Choose Any webform. Click on edit of that webform you will see list of fields available in that webform.
2. Select any of the field and click on edit option provided. You will see one popup is opened.
3. On that popup if you scroll down little you will find your required option. Please refer attached screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I'm aware of the ability to edit the placement of the element title. What  I am looking for is placement options for the Field Label.  For reference I am using Webform 8.x-5.0-beta15.

Comment: @BenStark I think you will need upload a screenshot showing what you mean by "Field label", since the Webform module does not actually use fields Field API.